# Users besides superuser cannot login in frontend

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I checkt the log and temp folders in global configuration the paths are correct.

The user groups are also assigned correctly.

I created a test user and cant log in into the frontend unless having superuser permissions.

The site was also not migrated from joomla 2.5 but built with 3.

Comment: It looks like you've changed something, because such behavior is not normal, of course. If you can, just reinstall Joomla - should help and will take much less time to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Goto global configuration->permission tab,
select "public" -> site login set to "Not set", Now you can login in frontend